# os.remove can't find file because of slashes

Tags: python, xbmc

I want to remove a file. That file was created earlier by the same program that I want to delete it.

This is what I have:

```
USER_FILE_NAME = 'user_info.json'
file_to_delete = os.path.join(ADDON_DATA['profile_dir'], USER_FILE_NAME)
xbmc.log('File to delete:')
print(file_to_delete)
os.remove(file_to_delete)
```

This is What I get (usernames and the likes were redacted due to paranoid tendencies):

```
NOTICE: File to delete:
NOTICE: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\XBMC\userdata\addon_data\script.NAME\user_info.json
NOTICE: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\XBMC\\userdata\\addon_data\\script.NAME\\user_info.json'
```

I think it is because of those damn slashes. I tried all sorts of things, but nothing seems to work. No matter what I did to the string in `file_to_delete`, including but really not limited to replacing the backslashes with forward slashes, the file it tried to find and delete was always the same as in the error line.

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**

So I tried something. I added `os.remove(repr(file_to_delete))` after the original `os.remove(file_to_delete)`, so I now have this:

```
if os.path.exists(file_to_delete):
    xbmc.log('User file exists, Prepairing to delete')
    xbmc.log('stats: %s' % os.access(file_to_delete, os.F_OK))
    xbmc.log('stats: %s' % os.access(file_to_delete, os.W_OK))
    xbmc.log('stats: %s' % os.access(file_to_delete, os.X_OK))
    os.remove(file_to_delete)
    os.remove(repr(file_to_delete))
```

If I comment out `os.remove(repr(file_to_delete))`, I get the same error as before.
If I don't comment that one but do the one above it, I get this error:

```
User file exists, Prepairing to delete
stats: True
Previous line repeats 2 times.
ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
.
.
.
os.remove(repr(file_to_delete))
    WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "u'C:\\\\Users\\\\USERNAME\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\XBMC\\\\userdata\\\\addon_data\\\\script.NAME\\\\user_info.json'"
```

If I don't comment either one and run in like it is, I get the same error as above but the file **IS REMOVED**. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE 2:**

The behavior above also happens in this instance:

```
os.remove(file_to_delete)
os.remove(file_to_delete)
```

File is removed, but get the error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\XBMC\\userdata\\addon_data\\script.NAME\\user_info.json'
```

When I use `os.remove()` with a different file in the same folder, both built with `os.path.join()`, once is enough.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try wrapping your instantiation of ```file_to_delete``` with ```os.path.abspath()```.  So ```file_to_delete = os.path.abspath(...)```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: Are you sure you are saving the file as `.json` and not possibly something like `.json.txt`?

Comment: @moooeeeep Yes, I'm sure. First thing I tried was copying the path in the error and pasting it in the run box.

Comment: @nwalsh Yes, the same way as in my reply above this one. The file opened.

Comment: @wnnmaw Tried it again just now, same error.

Comment: @koogle5000, do you have permissions to remove the file?  Also, what platform are you on?

Comment: @wnnmaw I'm on windows 7 and I do have permissions to remove the file.

Comment: @koogle5000, am I correct in assuming that ```os.path.exists()``` returns ```False```?

Comment: Add a `print "exists:", os.path.exists(file_to_delete)` right before the `os.remove()` call.

Comment: Result of `os.path.exists(file_to_delete)`:

`    NOTICE: exists:
    NOTICE: True`

Comment: How is the file created? Are you the one creating it manually or is your program creating the file before this function is ran?
Also, is your program threaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I found the problem. I put `time.sleep(2)` after `os.remove(file_to_delete)` and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The file name string appear to be encoded as a unicode string.

Perhaps try this:

```
file_to_delete= unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', file_to_delete).encode('ascii','ignore')
os.remove(file_to_delete)
```